# Minimal symmetry group of polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

Is there a polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose symmetry group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\backslash 3\mathbb{Z}$?

I believe I found such a polygon, it’s an equilateral triangle with $3$ smaller equilateral triangles cut out on each side. My idea was to maintain the rotational symmetries, and eliminate the reflectional symmetries. This shape has $12$ vertices.

I am wondering if there is a polygon with less than $12$ vertices that has symmetry group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\backslash 3\mathbb{Z}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the [triskelion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskelion#:~:text=A%20triskelion%20or%20triskeles%20is,represent%20three%20bent%20human%20legs).

Comment: @Shaun None of the pictures in the link are a polygon, so you should link to a polygonal realization you have in mind instead.

Comment: Well, yes, it is; the triskelion can be in the form of a polygon, @arctictern.

Comment: You can even find a convex hexagon with this symmetry group. It is easy to see that 6 is the smallest number of vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (skew) three-pointed ninja star has six vertices:

[image: ninjastar]

This is minimal. Suppose we have a polygon $P$ with $\mathbb{Z}_3$ symmetry. Any orbit other than the origin has three vertices. If there were only one triangular orbit, the polygon would either be an equilateral triangle or (if we include the center) three equal line segments at $120^\circ$ from each other, and in either case the full symmetry group is dihedral. Thus there are at least two triangular orbits, for a minimum of six vertices.

Comment: That's a triskelion.

Comment: @Shaun I'd say triskelion if there were whorls but this ain't exactly the ELU stackexchange I guess. Wikipedia does technically say there were ancient triskelions which came in the form of three legs, so with some license I can see it applying.

Comment: Who says a triskelion has to have "whorls"?

Comment: I didn't hear it from a person, I just read the Wikipedia link you gave, and looked through all the examples on it, and through the examples on the google image search I did.